# Lua pattern text split

Tags: lua

Again I need help with Lua patterns. Lets say i have following strings:

`<c> block` - should match `c` and `block`

`<category>material` - should match `category` and `material`

`decorative` - if there is no `<>` block then it should return what it was given (or nil).

I'm not interested in spaces, so built in trim would be nice.

I managed to create `(<%a>)([^>]+)`, but it returns `<c>` and `block` in first example, whish sadly is not what i'm after.

Comment: Try `<(%a+)>%s*([^>]+)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(<%a>)` part in your pattern captures the angle brackets thus they land in the captured value. The `%a` matches only one alpha char, so you need to add `+` quantifier after it to match 1 or more alpha chars.

Use

```
<(%a+)>%s*([^>]+)
```

The `%s*` will match 0+ whitespace chars and they will be outside Group 2.

A [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/2JpFMI):

```
local function splitString(text)
    return string.match(text, "<(%a+)>%s*([^>]+)")
end

print(splitString("<c> block"))           -- c  block
print(splitString("<category>material"))  -- category   material
print(splitString("decorative"))          -- nil
```

Comment: People here are truly genius. Thanks.

Comment: Just do not use global vars inside function :)

Comment: @moteus OK, a one-liner now :)